# How to get notified of incoming calls on mobile phone on laptop?

Tags: bluetooth, notifications, telephony

The reason for this is that my phone will be in vibrate mode, and I almost always forget to switch back to "General" profile after I reach my room from class. Hence I miss a lot of phone calls when the phone is not in my pocket.

When I reach home, my laptop will be always on. So it would be awesome if I get notification of phone calls on my desktop, and if I am AFK, play a ringtone on my laptop.

I want my laptop to present itself as a Bluetooth car audio system to my android phone, and then get notified of incoming calls on my (Arch) linux desktop.
I **don't** want a solution that involves WiFi or Mobile data.

An app/project called LINCONNECT does this, but via WiFi. But I don't have a WLAN available. That's why I insist on bluetooth, which also takes less toll on the battery.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, how to make it possible?

Comment: you can try this project [android-notifier](https://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/)

Comment: @Fred great find, I suggest you turn it to an answer!

Comment: What telephone do you use?

Comment: @techraf Android, rooted.

Answer (score 6):

You can can use [HFP](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/) to let the laptop act as bluetooth hands free device and configure such notifications.

From the homepage:

> HFP for Linux is a Bluetooth Hands-Free Profile server.
>
> It allows your Linux system to act as a speakerphone for your mobile phone. It aims to be a compliant Bluetooth HFP 1.5 Hands Free implementation, supporting all required commands and notifications, as well as streaming audio.

For your usecase, especially the HFP daemon should be of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just what I was looking for. I'll give it a try and accept the answer.

Comment: To my dismay, the project has been dead since 2010, it uses qt3, heavily outdated libraries etc. I've tried to get it to run, but with no luck.

Comment: This is the error I get: `HFPD: Error connecting to local SDP`

Answer (score 1):

If you were connected to the internet on both devices, how about using [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)? I guess you also have a browser on most of the time.

You would get not only incoming calls notifications, but any notification (which you can filter out).

Comment: I can't connect to the internet as I don't have WiFi.

Comment: I understand, but it was not clear. You could have a data plan on your phone and a PC connected to Ethernet with cable. That's why I used "if."

Answer (score 1):

you can try this project [android-notifier](https://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/)

Comment: This one also looks a bit outdated, but I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing [Missed Call & SMS to email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aes.incomingcalldetector&hl=en) application on your phone. This way, you can simply fetch information about missed calls with your favorite e-mail reader. Many e-mail readers support notification pop-ups / sounds.

Note that this will require your phone to have a data plan (I assume your laptop already has an Internet connection). There's even an advantage of receiving the notifications even if you don't have the phone on you when you get home.

Comment: My phone is not connected to the internet.